# Making local C package widely available

Tags: c

I'm using [this C package](https://github.com/stevengj/cubature) for numerical integration in several implementations. So far, what I do is copy the associated folder (after downloading the `cubature-master` in Github) into the same directory of my scripts, include the package as

```
#include "cubature-master/cubature.h"
```

and add the corresponding flag when compiling my code. I'm doing all of this locally on my Mac `arm64`. As suggested in the comments, I compiled the package via `CMake` and I got these results:

```
Sebastians-Macbook-Pro:cubature-master surrutiaquir$ cd build Sebastians-Macbook-Pro:build surrutiaquir$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 13.0.0.13000029
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 13.0.0.13000029
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/surrutiaquir/Software/cubature-master/build Sebastians-Macbook-Pro:build surrutiaquir$ make Scanning dependencies of target cubature [ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/cubature.dir/hcubature.c.o [ 66%] Building C object CMakeFiles/cubature.dir/pcubature.c.o [100%] Linking C shared library libcubature.dylib ld: warning: ignoring file CMakeFiles/cubature.dir/pcubature.c.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64 ld: warning: ignoring file CMakeFiles/cubature.dir/hcubature.c.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64 [100%] Built target cubature Sebastians-Macbook-Pro:build surrutiaquir$ make install [100%] Built target cubature Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libcubature.dylib
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/cubature.h
```

I would like to have the package in a single location but I'm not skilled enough to reference that path during the compiling process. My goal is to create a `Makefile` to deal with all of this. Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The answer to this question will depend heavily on your target operating system and what build platform you are using (make, CMake, etc.)

Comment: Hopefully, _your_ code is in a git repo. If so, you can track the cubature repo using `git submodule` or `git remote`.

Comment: You can clone from github on the fly to build with your latest commits or you can grab your latest release. I'm a bit confused on why you would need to "copy the folder"? Maybe that it what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks! I have added more details. Hopefully, they will help.

Comment: The library comes with CMake configuration. Consider learning CMake and using it instead of 50-year old grandpa make.

Comment: To me the last messages of your CMake build suggest that header and library are installed in paths usable by any project: "/usr/local/...". Did you try to simply `#include <cubature.h>` in your sources and then link with `-lcubature`?